# Check if two different values appear successively in a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There's a table that looks like this (there are more columns, but not relevant to the query):

```
DocumentId | DocumentStateId | TransitionMoment
111222       -2                2016-04-21
111222       -1                2016-04-22
111222       -7                2016-04-23
111222       -5                2016-04-24
111222       -6                2016-04-25
111222       -1                2016-04-26
333141       -2                2016-05-01
333141       -7                2016-05-09
333141       -6                2016-05-10
333141       -3                2016-05-15
777525       -1                2016-02-10
777525       -6                2016-02-10
777525       -7                2016-02-10
777525       -5                2016-02-10
777525       -2                2016-02-10
```

What options do I have to check whether a document has went from state "-7" to state "-6" consecutively (without transitioning through other states in between)? In the example Document no. 33141.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can a DocumentId have multiple -7 values, or -6 values?

Comment: Yes, it can have multiple -7 or -6 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would just use `lag()`.  In SQL Server 2005, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.documentid = t.documentid and
            t2.transitionmoment > t.transitionmoment
      order by t2.transitionmoment desc
     ) tnext
where t.DocumentStateId = -7 and
      tnext.DocumentStateId = -6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LEAD():

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
DocumentId, DocumentStateId, TransitionMoment,
LEAD(DocumentStateId) OVER (ORDER BY TransitionMoment) NextSIDVal,
LEAD(DocumentId) OVER (ORDER BY DocumentId) NextDIDVal
FROM Table
)

SELECT DocumentId, DocumentStateId, TransitionMoment FROM CTE
WHERE DocumentStateId = -7 AND NextSIDVal = -6
AND DocumentId = NextDIDVal
```

Using ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
DocumentId, DocumentStateId, TransitionMoment, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransitionMoment) RowVal
FROM Table
)

SELECT x.DocumentId, x.DocumentStateId, x.TransitionMoment
FROM CTE x
JOIN CTE y
ON x.RowVal + 1 = y.RowVal
WHERE x.DocumentStateId = -7 AND y.DocumentStateId = -6
AND x.DocumentId = y.DocumentId
```